# Android Emulator not detected in VScode [ubuntu]

Tags: android, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I  created an emulator using `sdkmanager` and `avdmanager` and ran it with `emulator` yet on restarting VScode, [it couldn't detect the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GeQ3.png)

`flutter devices` output:

```
2 connected devices:

Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.15.0-48-generic
Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 106.0.xxx.xx
```

`flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.4, on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS 5.15.0-48-generic, locale en_IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed
      instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I have only installed comandline tools from android studio and added to path.(which i expected to work) and havn't installed Android Studio thus that flutter doctor output is expected. So is there any way around this? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not set the emulator path at bash_profile.

Open a terminal and type     `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`    
Add     `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator`    if not there.
ps: make sure     `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`     is also present above  `PATH=$PATH:$...`